# ResponseModel Method in RestOperationResponseMsgDefinition of Apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger

I have written a sample route using latest camel version 2.16.0,importing camel-swagger-java library

```
 rest()
        .get("/health")
            .description("Health Check route")
            .produces("application/json")
            .param()
                .name("rest").description("rest param").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String")
            .endParam()
            .responseMessage()
                .code(200).responseModel(User.class).message("success")
            .endResponseMessage()
            .to("direct:health")
```

The schema generated is

```
"/health" : {
  "get" : {
    "tags" : [ "" ],
    "summary" : "Health Check route",
    "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
    "parameters" : [ {
      "name" : "rest",
      "in" : "query",
      "description" : "rest param",
      "required" : true,
      "type" : "string"
    } ],
    "responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "description" : "success"
      }
    },
    "x-camelContextId" : "camel-1",
    "x-routeId" : null
  }
},
```

In the above route,How does the method **responseModel** is used ? What is the use of it? Can any one give a sample example of its usage.I know that outType(User.class) and annotating the User.class will put it in the Response/Schema Model of Swagger UI.But what does the responseModel(class)  method do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah that was another missing functionality. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9447 and in the next release the responseModel class is now included in the generated swagger model.